# How does HandlerThread process messages?

Tags: android, handler, surfaceview

I'm implementing my own [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which contains a Thread object whose purpose is to draw various graphical objects to the Canvas. In the constructor of my SurfaceView, I set up the objects to be drawn and the Thread object (currently) only positions them to the Canvas as appropriate.

I have need now to change one of the objects created in the constructor of my SurfaceView (the object is a Bitmap) after the user has performed a particular action (i.e. the Thread object is running). This means communication between the app's GUI thread and the thread executing my Thread object. I discovered [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) page which details the use of the [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) class, perfect for what I need to achieve. However I need to be sure of how this class works to ensure there is no memory consistency errors.

The following is psuedo code of my own class with a lot stripped out for clarity:

```
public MyThread extends Thread {
    boolean _run = true;
    public void run(){

        // Create HandlerThread object
        // Create Looper object
        // Create Handler object
        while (_run){
            // DRAW the Bitmap in this loop
        }
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message message){
        /*
        ALTER the Bitmap here as required
        */
    }
}


public MyThread extends Thread {
    boolean _run = true;
    public void run(){

        // Create HandlerThread object
        // Create Looper object
        // Create Handler object
        while (_run){
            // DRAW the Bitmap in this loop
        }
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message message){
        /*
        ALTER the Bitmap here as required
        */
    }
}
```

As I understand it the `handleMessage()` method is executed by the same thread executing the `run()` method. However because `handleMessage()` ALTERS the the Bitmap whereas `run()` DRAWS the bitmap. Can I be sure that `handleMessage()` will complete in its entirety before the thread returns to the `run()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the question??

you're extending a regular Thread class in both cases, which don't inherently do anything special. process execute in serialized fashion unless you otherwise specified `run` and `handleMessage` to be run from different CALLING threads. so my guess is yes. that should be a fairly straightforwards thread safe execution pattern - if you're calling `handleMessage` and `run` in the same thread, then there's not reason they shouldn't be synchronized. if you're calling the two methods from different threads, (or if you're super worried and can't find the answer anywhere else), you can always lock on an object monitor by using `synchronized(myLock)` in both methods like:

```
public MyThread extends Thread {
    boolean _run = true;
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this) {
            while (_run){
            // DRAW the Bitmap in this loop
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message message){
        synchronized(this){...}
    }
}
```